# Power plug adapter for Thailand for US electronics

Tags: thailand, power

I live in the USA and will be traveling to Thailand in a few months. I'm trying to figure out if I need a travel adapter to plug my electronic devices into.

All my electronic devices support voltages from 100 to 240 V but as for the physical connector... I don't know.

https://www.power-plugs-sockets.com/us/thailand/ says I need a "need a power plug adapter in Thailand" but then again I'm not sure how much I trust that site because, according to that site, people living in Thailand also "need a power plug adapter" per https://www.power-plugs-sockets.com/th/thailand/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No adapter needed.  Your flat blade plugs will fit just fine in 98% of the outlets

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country), Thailand has types A, B, and C plugs while the USA has A and B. A is the two-prong no-grounding plug you're familiar with and B is the three-prong grounded plug you're familiar with also. (There are pictures down the side of the huge table on that page.) C is the two-prong Euro style plug, so if that was all that was available in a place you would need an adapter, but it seems likely that hotels and such will have those adapters if needed, since the other kinds of plug are also in use in the country.

To be on the totally safe side, take an adapter to convert two-prong A (your electronics) to two-prong C (possibly the plugs in some rooms.) You may never use it though. To live a little more dangerously, buy one of those in Thailand if and when you come to need it.

Comment: Thailand sockets are designed to take all three (as per the pictures you linked to on Wikipedia).  There is zero need for an adapter.